# Degeneracy in a two-level system of distinguishable particle

Tags: statistical-mechanics, two-level-system

If we consider $2$ distinguishable particles and two possible energies: $0$ and $0.01$eV.
Then while reading about this in books it's mentioned that this is considered as a non-degenerate system.

But how is that true?

Suppose I take a particle $x$ in $0$ev and another particle $y$ in $0.01$ev and another case where $x$ is in $0.01$ and $y$ in $0$.

These two cases are two different states but have same energy so isn't this degenerate?
Please also write the partition function for this:

Will it include power 2?
and will it include a degeneracy factor of 2?

Comment: If they were indistinguishible, it would be degenerate. Energy is not the sole "label" of state. If not, what is the difference between an electron with 0.5 eV and a positron with the same energy? would you call this the same state?

Comment: I did not say energy is the label of state. I said that particle a in 1 and b in 2 is a different state from particle a in 2 and b in 1.

Comment: is your question witbin quantum mechanics? that is where degenerate energy levels appear https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_energy_levels .

Comment: @ anna v Thanks for replying. My question is within statistical mechanics.

Comment: @anna v Is there something wrong with how I've worded the question? How should I change it to get answers?

Comment: in classical statistics many particles can be at the energy E http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Kinetic/statcom.html . It is not named as degeneracy. it is quantized states that can be degenerate

Comment: When I interchange two particles from "those many particles" it certainly gives a new state but with the same energy. How is this not degeneracy?

Comment: I think this may be a case of terminology, "degenerate" applied to energy levels means two or more states with the same energy. But the term "degenerate" is sometimes used more loosely in statistical physics, to refer to the case where the average number of particles per state is non-negligible, with the result that distinguishability issues become important.

Comment: @Andrew Steane  So in my case, is there degeneracy or not for the statistical case, that is to ask, while calculating the partition function do I take the factor of $g=2$ here or not? Since particle exchange creates a different state (due to distinguishabilty)

Comment: @Lost I added an answer to give my response to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning in this example is sound. If the single-particle states are $d$ and $u$ then the four states $|dd\rangle,|du\rangle,|ud\rangle,|uu\rangle$ have energies $0, E, E, 2E$. Hence the partition function is
$$
Z = e^0 + e^{-\beta E} + e^{-\beta E} + e^{-\beta 2E}
= 1 + 2 e^{-\beta E} + e^{-\beta 2E}.
$$
Thus there are four states but three energy levels of the complete system of 2 particles. The energy levels in this example have degeneracies $g = 1,2,1$ respectively.

Comment: Oh okay so that's why when we were taught about this we were not told separately about the degeneracy since we had written the formula for Partition Function as:$$ P.F.=Z^2$$ where $$Z=\sum e^{-\beta\epsilon_i}$$. This gives exactly what you have written where the cross-term $2a*b$ would correspond to showing the degeneracy.

Comment: So does this basically mean that for distinguishable particles there will always be degeneracy if there is more than 1 energy level? And that is why for weakly-interacting distinguishable particles we consider them as independent sub-systems and write the formula for their partition function as given in Wikipedia:
$$Z=ζ^N$$ (when the sub-systems are exactly the same) 
for N particles, the power accounting for the degeneracy? That is to ask, whether the formulas $$Z=Z_1*Z_2...*Z_N$$ and $$Z=Z=∑g_i e^{−βϵ} $$ are equal to each for distinguishable particles?

Comment: Could you please answer the question in the comments? Almost everything is cleared from my confusion by your and ytlu's amswer. Your comment on the the question i asked above would clear the remaining doubt. Thank you.

Comment: @Lost yes, as long as the sum in the last expression is a sum over energy levels of the composite system. It is a useful exercise to prove that the product of $Z_j$ can indeed always be written in this way. I showed the proof for two systems; you can try for three systems and then for any number of systems (or consult a textbook).

Answer (score 1):

The term "degenerate" had used abusely. In quantum mechanics, "degnerate" means two independent state of same energy. Similarly, in statistics, the "degeneracy"  number of different configurationsof a given energy.

Here, the OP posted a text which define "non-degenerate" if two configurations are composed of two distingushable particles. This is an example of inappropriate usage of this term .

Consider the example in the post: two particles $x$, $y$ and two states $\epsilon_1$, $\epsilon_2$, therefore, we have this two configuraions:

\begin{align*}
  C_1 =& \vert x=\epsilon_1, y=\epsilon_2>;\\
  C_2 =& \vert x=\epsilon_2, y=\epsilon_1>.\\
&\\
E =& \epsilon_1 + \epsilon_2.
\end{align*}

The configurations $C_1$ and $C_2$ are certainly two degerate arrangements in energy. How much do they give contributions to the partition function?
$$
  Z = \int_E g(E) exp\left(-\beta E\right).
$$

1. if $x$ and $y$ are indistinguishable, the $C_1$ and $C_2$ gives only one count to $g(E)$.
2. but they gives 2 counts to $g(E)$ if $x$ and $y$ are distinguishable.

Because, the density of states $g(E)$ is also called the degneracy (or multiplicity) of energy $E$. But naming the case 2 "non-degenerate" is certainly not appropriate.

If there is $N_1$ particles of species 1, and $N_2$ particles of species 2:
The total partition function of will be if these two species are distiguishable:
$$\tag{1}
Z^{distinguish}(N_1, N_2) = Z_1(N_1) \times Z_2(N_2).
$$

If they are indistinguishable, a factor of 2 have to divide for each particle to be in the group of $N_1$ or in $N_2$:
$$ \tag{2}
Z^{indistinguish}(N_1, N_2) = \frac{1}{2^{N_1+N_2}} Z_1(N_1) Z_2(N_2).
$$
A factor $1/2$ denotes the possiblility of two choice for each particle.

For indistinguishable particle, we can further to examine the combination of two parties for non-interaction particles
\begin{align}
Z_1 = \frac{1}{N_1!} z_1^{N_1};\\
Z_2 = \frac{1}{N_2!} z_2^{N_2}
\end{align}

Summing over all possible splitings of $N_1 + N_2 = N$ for Eq.(2), renders
\begin{align}
Z_{total}^{indistinguish}(N) =& \sum_{N_1 = 0}^N \frac{1}{N_1! N_2 !} \left(\frac{z_1}{2}\right)^{N_1} \left(\frac{z_2}{2}\right)^{N_2} ;\\
=& \frac{1}{N!} \sum_{N_1 = 0}^N \frac{N!}{N_1! N_2 !} \left(\frac{z_1}{2}\right)^{N_1} \left(\frac{z_2}{2}\right)^{N_2} ;\\
= &\frac{1}{N!} \left( \frac{z_1}{2} + \frac{z_2}{2}  \right)^N.\\
= &\frac{1}{N!}  z_1^N.
\end{align}

We recover the partition for $N$ indistinguishable particles.

Comment: Maybe I have not put my question properly. I am in favour of the view that in this example the energy level is degenerate. The books and other source say that the Partition Function of this is: $PF=Z^2$. It doesn't seem to take into account the degeneracy plus there is a square on the power which I figured from Wikipedia but does that take into account the degeneracy?

Comment: I edited adding some verses to address a combination system.

Comment: In equation 1, have you assumed that the particles of species 1 are indistinguishable among themselves?

Comment: Also, for my system will the partition function be: $$Z=[\sum e^{-\beta \epsilon_j}]^2$$  or    $$Z=\sum g_i  e^{-\beta \epsilon_j}$$ where $g_i=2$?

Comment: 1. Yes. $N_1$ and $N_2$ are two indistinguishable systems. That will reflected in the details of Z_1 and Z_2, not shown in the post irrelavent for now..... 2. the partition function is $Z = \sum g_i e^{-\beta \epsilon_i}$ for $N_1$. If you have two distinguishable system both have particle number $N$, the partition function will be $Z = Z_1(N) \times Z_2(N) $. It just the combination of two systems. They are not necessary of a same energy structure $g_1$ and $g_2$. If the are same energy structure, then $Z_1 \times Z_2 = Z^2$.

Comment: How do I infer in such cases that each particle is itself has to be treated like a sub-system and that the multiplication formula applies and the degeneracy formula for partition function has to be applied for individual particles? So for instance, since I saw that one energy level can have two states I took $g=2$ and then simply wrote the partition function for the "whole system" as: $$Z=∑g_i e^{−βϵ}$$. Now I didnt know what were $g_1$ and $g_2$ for my system and took both as 2 which gives the wrong result obviously.

Comment: So, does this formula only apply for individual particles when they are distinguishable since they have to be treated as sub-systems? or is that true in general? I am confused when to apply the power formula and when to apply the summation formula or do I have to apply both of them as you have done (which I don't find in books etc) and what to consider as a system and which to treat as sub-systems?

Comment: It is general rule. But when they are distinguish or indistinquish, you will count the permutation differently. $g_1$ and $g_2$ are the multiplicities of $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$ as the density of states. Here, they may be assume $1$ for simplicity, as the answer from Andrew Steane did.

Comment: Power formula is a decomposition of summation form. If there are no interaction, the summation will becomes a power of single-particle partition function. For distinquish particle $Z_N = (z_1)^N$, but for indistinguish  particle $Z_N = (z_1)^N /N!$